# How to decompose a list like this in scheme/lisp?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme

Input1:

```
(decompose '(* 1 2 3 4))
```

Output1:

```
'(* 1 (* 2 (* 3 4)))
```

Input2

```
(decompose '(+ 1 2 3 (* 5 6 7)))
```

Output2

```
'(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (* 5 (* 6 7)))))
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way as you would evaluate it, but instead of outputting the result, you simply output the expression that would be used.

Here's my implementation, tested on Racket:

```
(define (decompose expr)
  (define (expand x)
    (if (list? x)
        (decompose x)
        x))
  (define oper (car expr))
  (let next ((args (map expand (cdr expr))))
    (if (<= (length args) 2)
        (cons oper args)
        (list oper (car args) (next (cdr args))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you posted your own solution, so I guess it's ok to show my complete answer. Here's another possible implementation, as a mutually-recursive pair of procedures. I like the fact that this solution doesn't require using `length` or `list?` (which might entail unnecessary traversals over the list), and uses only elementary functions (no `foldr`, `reverse`, `map` or any other higher-order procedures are needed.)

```
(define (decompose lst)
  (if (or (null? lst)                     ; if the list is empty
          (null? (cdr lst))               ; or has only one element
          (null? (cddr lst)))             ; or has only two elements
      lst                                 ; then just return the list
      (process (car lst)                  ; else process car of list (operator)
               (cdr lst))))               ; together with cdr of list (operands)

(define (process op lst)
  (cond ((null? (cdr lst))                ; if there's only one element left
         (if (not (pair? (car lst)))      ; if the element is not a list
             (car lst)                    ; then return that element
             (decompose (car lst))))      ; else decompose that element
        ((not (pair? (car lst)))          ; if current element is not a list
         (list op                         ; build a list with operator,
               (car lst)                  ; current element,
               (process op (cdr lst))))   ; process rest of list
        (else                             ; else current element is a list
         (list op                         ; build a list with operator,
               (decompose (car lst))      ; decompose current element,
               (process op (cdr lst)))))) ; process rest of list
```

It works for your examples, and then some:

```
(decompose '(* 1 2 3 4))
=> '(* 1 (* 2 (* 3 4)))

(decompose '(+ 1 2 3 (* 5 6 7)))
=> '(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (* 5 (* 6 7)))))

(decompose '(+ 1 (* 4 5 6) 2 3))
=> '(+ 1 (+ (* 4 (* 5 6)) (+ 2 3)))

(decompose '(+ 1 2 3 (* 5 6 7) 8))
=> '(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ (* 5 (* 6 7)) 8))))

(decompose '(+ 1 2 3 (* 5 6 7) (* 8 9 10) (* 11 12 (- 1))))
=> '(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ (* 5 (* 6 7)) (+ (* 8 (* 9 10)) (* 11 (* 12 (- 1))))))))
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because it seems closest in spirit to mine, and because I dislike the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Modified from `Chris Jester-Young`'s solution:

```
(define (decompose x)
  (if (pair? x)
      (let ((operator (car x))
            (expanded-x (map decompose x)))
        (let decompose-helper ((operands (cdr expanded-x)))
          (if (<= (length operands) 2)
              (cons operator operands)
              (list operator (car operands) (decompose-helper (cdr operands))))))
      x))
```